# Why was this question about incompatible operant types closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I tackled [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65547966/2359227). It is fairly obvious that a junior, both in Stack Overflow and in Java (probably in coding in general) asked it.

I understand that they probably didn't tag it correctly, didn't format it correctly, and included some of the information that were supposed to be in the body, in the title. But, this question was closed due to missing debugging details. As we can see, there is pretty immediate two answers and one comment addressing the issue correctly. This probably means that there aren't any missing debugging details.

Should that question be reopened? Should it stay closed? If it stays closed, is it possible to change the closure reason?

Comment: If you are downvoting, can you please explain why? I didn't say this question should be reopened. I just flattened all options. Now I understand that the correct choice is leave it closed, and now it is already deleted.

Comment: Questions that have been asked dozens of times already tend to receive downvotes on meta. It's better to ask than to be left wondering or make an assumption and do the wrong thing so don't let it deter you from asking in the future. Secretly the meta dwellers actually enjoy showing off their epic knowledge of the site so they don't mind repeat questions at all, but they'll never admit it ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reopening to change the close reason is a waste of time. Seems like a typo question, with the asker unable to understand an extremely explicit error message.

At best, the question might a dupe of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430043/difference-between-char-and-string-in-java/10430082) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593801/incompatible-operand-types-char-and-string-java).

With questions like this one, spending a few seconds looking for a dupe is a better use of one's time than posting an answer.

Comment: _Reopening to change the close reason is a waste of time_ --> So if the OP's question gets closed as "needs details or clarity" when the question should actually be closed with "Opinion Based", you'll be fine when they get confused?

Comment: Yes, I'll be fine. It's not ideal, but it's better than the alternative. Reopening to close for a more accurate reason requires a lot of energy that's better spent elsewhere.